# How to change the tax amount in quote

Tags: checkout, tax, ce-1.9.1.0

I wish to change the tax amount in checkout programmatically I am using following code let me know If I am making any mistake.

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session");
$quote_id = $session->getQuoteId();
$quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->load($quote_id);
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item) { 
   $item->setTaxAmount(0);
   $item->setBaseTaxAmount(0);
   $item->setPriceInclTax($value);
   $item->setBasePriceInclTax($value);
   $item->save();
   $quote->save();
}
```

Comment: you use this code inside event observers?

Comment: I am using it in Model file

Comment: ok. Can you try with this event sales_quote_collect_totals_after

Comment: But I want to change this before placing order and only on checkout page

Comment: yes you can the tax with the above events

Comment: Can u give me solution why the above code is not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22758/discussion-between-pratik-bhatt-and-saravanavelu).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Long research and trials Finally I come up with this solution.

```
$finalPrice = $product->getPrice();
    $item = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);
    $finalprice = $finalPrice - $item->getTaxAmount();
    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    if ($address)
    {   $address->setSubtotalInclTax($finalprice);
        $product->setTaxClassId(0);
        $product->setPrice($finalprice);

     }
```

Comment: hi @Pratik, here i have similar question, can you update me please,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart