# How to set custom tax price during add to cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, addtocart, tax

I am adding product to cart using ajax call.

Here is my controller code.

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class AddItems extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

 protected $formKey;   
 protected $cart;
 protected $product;
 protected $_resource;
 protected $checkoutSession;
 protected $_taxCalculationService;
 protected $quoteRepository;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
\Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface $taxCalculationService,
\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
  array $data = []
) {
   $this->formKey = $formKey;
   $this->cart = $cart;
   $this->product = $product;     
   $this->_resource = $resource;
   $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;  
   $this->_taxCalculationService = $taxCalculationService; 
   $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    parent::__construct($context);
 }

 public function execute()
{ 

 try{
   $productId = 10;
    $params = array(
        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
        'product_id' => $productId, //product Id
        'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
    );
    $_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);       
     $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($_product );
    if($item){          
        $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();                   
        $quote->updateItem($item->getId(), array( 'qty' => 1));
        $quote->save();
    }else{                  
        $this->cart->addProduct($_product , $params);
    }
  $customPrice = 1000;
  $grossAmt = 550;

  $productTaxClassId = $_product->getTaxClassId();
  $customerId = $this->getCustomerId();
  $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
  $productRates = $this->_taxCalculationService->getCalculatedRate($productTaxClassId, $customerId, $storeId);

  $taxAmount = ((1 * $grossAmt * $productRates) / 100);

  $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
  $quoteId = $quote->getId();   
  $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product );                
  $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
  $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
  $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);   
  $this->cart->save(); 

   $productItem->setTaxAmount($taxAmount)->setBaseTaxAmount($taxAmount)->save(); 
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $quote->collectTotals();
    //$quote->save(); 
    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
   }
 }

public function getProductQuote($product) {
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();        
    $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);        
    return $cartItems;
}
 public function getCustomerId(){
    $customerId =  $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Using above code, I am able to add product to cart with custom price.

I need to add custom tax price also upon adding the product to cart. Right now tax is not getting applied.

How can I set custom tax price for the product added to cart.

Can anyone help me please, custom tax price I have got in variable,  **$taxAmount**

This code save the data to **"tax_amount"** and **"base_tax_amount"** fields in quote_item table but when navigated to cart page, tax is showing as 0 and in table values are restored to 0.

```
$productItem->setTaxAmount($taxAmount)->setBaseTaxAmount($taxAmount)->save(); 
             $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
             $quote->collectTotals();
             $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
            // $quote->save();
```

Please share the ideas where I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add fixed amout or % amount of product?

Comment: @SaphalJha, i need to add the Fixed amount, that value already i am getting in taxAmount variable.

Comment: @SaphalJha, I am looking for code how to set custom tax price when product added to cart using its id or sku

Comment: ok, I'll look for solution and update you

Comment: @SaphalJha, thanks,

Comment: do you mean, you need to add custom fee as tax to total?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, yes, correct, like i set custom price , how can we set custom tax price for that product?

Comment: please check this one : https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-pricefee-order-total-magento2/

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, this i have tested, I am not looking like that, i have product id, quote item, how can we set custom tax price, like the custom price i set over in my code, please look at my code once, I need to add tax price for the product added now, I have got the value in this varaible "$taxAmount", just i am looking for code how to set that as tax price

Comment: Have you create tax class for that product which you wat to apply?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, no, tax class not created for that product, that's why i need to set custom tax price for the product,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93616/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-dhiren-vasoya).

Comment: @SaphalJha, could you find any solution for it?

Comment: @jafarpinjar haven't tried this yet but I think it is possible.

Comment: @magefms, right now once i used above code, in quote_item table, tax_amount value updating but if come to cart page, its getting refreshed to 0 again

Comment: hmmm @jafarpinjar  can you check if the product is set as taxable goods or not otherwise it could be one of the possible reason why tax amount in cart page is refreshed to 0

Comment: @magefms, yes its set as taxable goods in admin

Comment: in checkout page ?

Comment: @RkRathod, yes, in cart and checkout page navigated means, it will reset to 0 again

Comment: @jafarpinjar - were you able to resolve the issue ? If yes, plz share your solution. It will be of great help

Comment: @ManashviBirla, No i didn't find the solution for it..

Comment: @jafarpinjar - any work around for this issue ?

Comment: @ManashviBirla, I tried with custom tax where added custom column as custom tax. pls refer extra fee module

Comment: @jafarpinjar did you get any solution

Comment: @mohith, No still no solution found for this, if u get any plesae update here

Answer (score 0):

capture event: sales_quote_add_item

You can set tax price for item on this event.

Comment: @light, can u update me answer pls, is there any way to set from controller?

Comment: if you would like to add from controller, I think you need to set quote items: 
$taxAmount = 100;
$cartItem = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);  
$cartItem->setTaxAmount($taxAmount)->setBaseTaxAmount($taxAmount)->save();
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();

Comment: This code I tried, but that didn't work for me, but setting custom price s working, tax amount not getting saved

Comment: hello @light, can you help in updating the observer code either, i trigger the mentioned event but looking for code in observer file.

Comment: @jafarpinjar got any solution ?

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari, No dear, not found the solution

Comment: do you know how can we remove tax programmatically   ?

Comment: please check the below link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170535/how-to-update-tax-amount-with-custom-price-in-magento-2/321744#321744

Answer (score 0):

You can observe to the event `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after` and achieve it.

**File : app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after">
        <observer name="changeTax" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeTax"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**File : app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeTax.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ChangeTax implements ObserverInterface
{


    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total */
        $total = $observer->getData('your_data');

    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Rathod, this will add the tax for total, not for the specific quote item is it? how can we apply fixed tax amount for specific quote item, like i set the custom price for quote item only

Comment: here you can received all the data of quote and you can change as per your requirment

Comment: if you don't mind, can you please update code for updating tax amount for specific quote item in the observer file? @Rathod, what need to be replaced in your_data?

Comment: in your_data you can get data which you want

Comment: in $observer which value getting you and get this value using getdata('your_data')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93708/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: This is probably the best answer so far but I think you can actually just add a totals collector.

Comment: @RkRathod,could you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: no bro i can try but not getting any solution

Comment: @ShawnAbramson, can you please update me the code for the totals.

Comment: How to set tax code here please advise