# Magento 2 create ajax request from out of magento

Tags: magento2, ajax, security

I wanna create Ajax request from empty HTML with jQuery.
I do like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://****.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=***&password=****",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (d) {
      alert(d);
    }
  });
```

but always I get error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=magento&password=magento2' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know I should add some header before send request but jquery does not support headers.
Anyone gets this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and check, use **`method`** instead of **type**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://****.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=***&password=****",
    method: "POST",
    success: function (d) {
      alert(d);
    }
});
```

Or with headers using **`jquery and prototype`**

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'prototype'
], function($){
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://****.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token",
    method: "POST",
    "headers": {
        "username": "magento",
        "password": "magento2"
    },
    success: function (d) {
    alert(d);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: hi @magefms, can you look into this issue and help me please,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Comment: @jafarpinjar let me check

Comment: Thank you @magefrms

Comment: hi @magefms, is it possible to set tax amount from controller, am i using correctly?

Comment: sorry ...it does not worked

Comment: @ghdarvishani what are you trying to achieve because it works for me

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bBsB5TCGpF/ it is my code ... i add jquery to page and prototype but does not worked