# Magento 2.3: How To Get The Primary Key From URL...?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, request

I'm very new to Magneto 2.3, I'm trying to get the primary key from URL, this is my code:

This is my import button, on click of this button, a function hit.

**/app/code/EC/Customimport/view/adminhtml/templates/form/import.phtml**

```
<div class="pp-buttons-container">
    <button class="import" id="<?php echo $block->getId() ?>" onclick="return false;">
        <span><span><span><?php echo 'Import'; ?></span></span></span>
    </button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery",'mage/url'], function($, url){
        "use strict";
        $(document).on('click','.col-action-grouped a',function(){
        });

        $(document).on('click','.import',function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/admin/customimport/index/import',
            type: "POST",
            data: data: {url_value : url},
            success: function(response){
                console.log('ABCD');
            }
        });
        });

    });
</script>
```

This is the file and in that file their is a function `execute`, where I'm trying to get the `primary key`, please see the code below:

**/app/code/EC/Customimport/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Import.php**

```
<?php

namespace EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use EC\Customimport\Model\CustomimportFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Import extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        Context $context,
        CustomimportFactory $modelCustomimportFactory
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->modelCustomimportFactory = $modelCustomimportFactory;
        $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(0);

        //$id = $this->request->getParams('customimport_id'); 
        //print_r($id);
        //exit;

        $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
        $id = $postData['customimport_id'];
        print_r($id);
        exit;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you want to get the id which show into URL, right?

Comment: $id = $this->request->getParam('customimport_id');

Comment: $id = $this->getRequest->getParams(''customimport_id'');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to update your phtml ajax code like this.

```
$(document).on('click','.import',function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/admin/customimport/index/import',
            type: "POST",
            data: {customimport_id : '<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('icustomimport_id'); ?>'},
            success: function(response){
                console.log('ABCD');
            }
        });
```

Now replace your controller code like this.

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParams('customimport_id'); 
print_r($id);
exit;
```

Or try this code.

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
$id = $postData['customimport_id'];
print_r($id);
exit;
```

Comment: hello @Dhiren,did you found any solution for this issue?https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Comment: You mean only this code in `execute()` ... ??? @DhirenVasoya

Comment: @SaifZakir yes, so this code give you 5 which show into your screen-sort.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Got nothing please see updated code and image......

Comment: @SaifZakir I update the answer, and kindly check that you use $this->getRequest() into your code, note like $this->request.

Comment: Still Got Nothing Question Updated.... :(

Comment: but into your data variable from ajax you need to pass that things, then you are able to get it here.

Comment: but how do i pass it, you mean replace `data: 'success'` with `url`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93669/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-saif-zakir).

Comment: @DhirenVasoya `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274728/magento-2-3-sqlstate21000-cardinality-violation-1241-operand-should-contain?noredirect=1#comment391401_274728` ............. :P

Comment: Bro @DhirenVasoya please help me out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276387/magento-2-custom-js-not-working-when-adding-more-than-1-js

Answer (score 0):

Try passing data like this in import.phtml

```
<div class="pp-buttons-container">
<button class="import" id="<?php echo $block->getId() ?>" onclick="return false;">
    <span><span><span><?php echo 'Import'; ?></span></span></span>
</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["jquery",'mage/url'], function($, url){
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('click','.col-action-grouped a',function(){
    });

    $(document).on('click','.import',function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/admin/customimport/index/import',
        type: "POST",
        data: {customimport_id :'Some Value'},
        success: function(response){
            console.log('ABCD');
        }
    });
    });

});
```

And get the value in controller like

```
use EC\Customimport\Model\CustomimportFactory;
```

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Import extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $request;

```
/**
 * @param Context $context
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    Context $context,
    CustomimportFactory $modelCustomimportFactory
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->modelCustomimportFactory = $modelCustomimportFactory;
    $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute(){
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);

    //$id = $this->request->getParams('customimport_id'); 
    //print_r($id);
    //exit;

    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); 
    $id = $postData['customimport_id'];
    print_r($id);
    exit;
}
```

}

Comment: tried but getting an error of invalid path....

Comment: update the code where you have passed the data and controller code for retrieving it..

Comment: updated........

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Bro @aravind please help me out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276387/magento-2-custom-js-not-working-when-adding-more-than-1-js