# Magento 2.3: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3, query

I'm very new to magento 2.3, I'm facing some error maybe from DB side....

Here is my code:

**/app/code/EC/Customimport/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Import.php**

```
<?php

namespace EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use EC\Customimport\Model\CustomimportFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Import extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        Context $context,
        CustomimportFactory $modelCustomimportFactory
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->modelCustomimportFactory = $modelCustomimportFactory;
        $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(0);

        $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParams('customimport_id'); 

            $model = $this->modelCustomimportFactory->create()->load($id);
            $model->import();

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/*/index');
        return $resultRedirect;

    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s),
query was: 
SELECT `customimport`.* FROM `customimport` 
WHERE 
(`customimport`.`customimport_id`='true', '4', 'FrFt7XBKVOwNwaq2')
```

Comment: what is the (`customimport`.`customimport_id`='true', '4', 'FrFt7XBKVOwNwaq2')?

Comment: A query.........

Comment: I know, but customimport_id's value why like  'true', '4', 'FrFt7XBKVOwNwaq2'?

Comment: basically `customimport` is a table in my `DB` & `customimport_id='4'`

Comment: @RutveeSojitra don't know why its making a wrong query.....

Comment: share complete code of import.php file into question.

Comment: you mean complete controller ?

Comment: Yes, I need to check which model class you declare?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParams('customimport_id'); => $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customimport_id');