# What are the best blogs for Magento 2 tutorial?

Tags: magento2, learning

I'm learning **Magento 2** and would like to improve my skill in Magento. I can see that there are a lot of blogs available for Magento tutorial but, could you please suggest me the **best blog for Magento 2 tutorial**?.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want learn a very basic thing you should follow:

**webKul Blog**

**https://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/**

**https://www.mageplaza.com/**

But if you want to learn all magento thing conceptually No one better than below blogs:

https://devdocs.magento.com/#/individual-contributors

https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/

Comment: hi @Rutvee,can you help me on this issue?https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out these video tutorials which are pretty awesome: https://www.mage2.tv

Comment: This is a paid service

Comment: @DominicXigen it is, but it's really good. Also the op never _specifically_ stated they want only free tutorials :)