# Custom price in cart not working in Magento 2.3.1 observer

Tags: event-observer, addtocart, magento2.3.1, custom-prices

I am developing a magento site for furniture sale. I have some grouped products.

If a customer add `1 piece` of any product of the group to cart, the special price will be added to cart.

If the customer add more than 1 piece of any product of the group to cart, the cost price will be added to cart.

Suppose, in grouped product, Product A has

```
regular price: $989.99 
special price: $732.99 
cost price: $669.99
```

If a customer add **1 quantity** to the cart, the subtotal price will be **$732.99** and if the customer add `3 quantity` to the cart, the subtotal price will be `2009.97` **($669.99 * 3)**.

To do the funtionality, I have created a `observer` and set the custom price as cost price but it always add special price, not the cost price. Can anyone help me to figure out the issue?

**Here is the events.xml:**

```
**app/code/vendor_name/module_name/etc/events.xml**

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Vendor_name\Module_name\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Here is the observer file: app/code/vendor_name/module_name/Observer/CustomPrice.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor_name\Module_name\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;


class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

        $price = $item->getProduct()->getCost(); //set your price here

        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Get Product Special Price Like This :-**

```
$price = $item->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice();
```

Comment: hi @Rathod, in my case setting custom price working fine, but tax price not getting updated, here is my question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart-in-magento-2

Comment: let me check...

Comment: I am getting special price correctly but I need cost price? How can I get that?

Comment: $item->getProduct()->getCost() using this which price you get ???

Comment: The special price @Rk Rathod

Comment: ok i will check

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code, It may be helpful to resolve your issue:**

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');

$item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$prodObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
$price = $prodObj->getCost(); //set your price here

$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

}

Comment: It's not working. Thank for your help.

Comment: checkout_cart_product_add_after is tracking only the last item. When I am adding multiple items of the grouped product at time. Only the last item price got updated. Others are remaining the same. please advise

Answer (score 0):

For grouped product I have looped through all the product if multiple products added to basket at the same.

```
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    try {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
        $items = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        foreach ($items->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $price = $this->priceHelper->getPrice($item->getProduct(), $item->getQty());
          
            if ($price != null) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```